# How to Pass and Save the Facebook User's Information values from script to server?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, facebook

I have fblogin to my site. I want to save  ID, name and email to database. So PLease tell me how to pass the those values from
script to server. Since am dont have much experince, I dont know how to pass the values from script to server. If its possible
to pass the values from script ta server. Kindly tell me the solution.

Below I have posted my complete coding

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title>Facebook Get Logged in User Details UserName,Email,Profile Image</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d) {
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
} (document));

// Init the SDK upon load
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId: 'XXXXX', // App ID
channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/channel', // Path to your Channel File
status: true, // check login status
cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
});

// listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
if (response.authResponse) {
// user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
//var uid = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.authResponse.userID + "/picture";
var uid = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.authResponse.userID + "/education ";
var uuu = "http://graph.facebook.com/me?education=" + response.authResponse.accessToken
FB.api('/me', function(me) {alert(me.first_name)
var Name = me.name;
var Email = me.email


})

document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
} else {
// user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
}
});
$("#auth-logoutlink").click(function() { FB.logout(function() { window.location.reload(); }); });
}
</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<h1>
    &nbsp;Facebook Login Authentication </h1>
<div id="auth-status">
<div id="auth-loggedout">
<div class="fb-login-button" autologoutlink="true" scope=" user_checkins,user_website, user_relationship_details, user_hometown, user_religion_politics, user_education_history, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_status, publish_stream, user_photos, read_stream, friends_likes">Login with Facebook</div>
</div>



<div id="auth-loggedin" style="display: none">
    <br />
    Name:<b><span id="auth-displayname"></span></b>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;(<a href="#" id="auth-logoutlink">logout</a>)<br />
First Name: <b><span id="firstname"></span></b><br />

Last Name: <b><span id="lastname"></span></b><br />

Email: <b><span id="Email"></span></b><br />

gender: <b><span id="gender"></span></b><br />

Dob of birth: <b><span id="birth"></span></b><br />

Location: <b><span id="location"></span></b><br />

</div>

    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible ways to transfer values from the client to the server are f.e. AJAX or an HTML form … up to you.

Comment: @CBroe:how to pass value using Ajax

Comment: SO is not the place to teach such basics. Please search the net for a tutorial or something.

Comment: @CBroe: I have found solution and answered the question. I cannot able to ask further question in my account. please give me a solution...

Comment: @CBroe: Please give a chance to post the question.

Comment: I can’t help you with that, you will have to contact a site administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have surfed the internet for last 2 days and found the soultion on my own to pass the value from client to server. Below I Have 
pasted the solution...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var data2Send = '{"fbid":"222222", "fbemail":"aaa@dsf.com", "fbsex":"Male", "fbdob":"22/03/1989"}';
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'passvaluw.aspx/Testmethod',
    data: data2Send,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (arg) {console.log(arg) //call successfull
    $("#lbltxt").text(arg.d);},
    error: function (xhr) {
        //error occurred
    }
});

</script>


 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string TestMethod(string fbid, string fbemail, string fbsex, string fbdob)
    {

return fbemail;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the user info in the server, then you need to use some server side language..
Suppose you use PHP, then in that case, you need to pass user info to the server and first check whether user info exists in your db or not..

> //connect with your database //request user info //query to get user
>   info from db
>
> if(you have user info in database){ //display user profile } 
>   else{
>   //upload to your database }